# record field have been truncated when using collect in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, record, collect, truncated

i have data with the structure like below
Node Labeled **"GROUP"**
**GROUP_NAME**
politician
worker
game
sports

Node Labeled **"MEMBER"**
**MEMBER_NAME**
a
b

Node Labeled **"MEMBERGROUP"**
**MEMBER_NAME|GROUP_NAME**
a|politician
a|worker
a|game
b|game
b|sports

Node Labeled **"MEMBERLIKES"**
**MEMBER_NAME|USER_LIKES**
a|business
a|lunch
a|rpg
b|rts
b|soccer

then i've wrap it all in node labeled "PROFILE"
**GROUP_NAME|USER_NAME|USER_LIKES**
politician|a|business
worker|a|lunch
game|a|rpg
game|b|rts
sports|b|soccer

what i would like to achieve are to wrap all those into single row data for each user, like below
**GROUP_NAME|USER_NAME|USER_LIKES**
politician,worker,game|a|business,lunch,rpg
game,sports|b|rts,soccer

but, when i'm using "COLLECT" statement

```
match (a:group) where tolower(a.group_name) CONTAINS 'game'
match (b:member)-[:rel_member_likes]->(c:memberlikes)<-[:rel_member_likes]-(d:member)
where NOT EXISTS ((d)<-[:rel_group_member]-(a))
return  COLLECT b.group_name , COLLECT b.user_name, COLLECT c.user_likes;
```

it throw me warning **"Record Fields have been truncated"** and not all data fetched and show in neo4j browser (*actually i have large dataset to collect*)
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are also doing a COLLECT() on b.username, it will not return you a row for each user. If you want to have a row for each user, you should do:

```
return  b.user_name, COLLECT b.group_name , COLLECT c.user_likes;
```

Comment: i did what you've suggested , but the warning "Record Fields have been truncated" is still coming. i'm using Neo4j Desktop 1.3.3, and database 4.1.0, OS Windows 10

Comment: What happens if you add a LIMIT 20 for instance?

Comment: Ok i'll try and i'll update the progress... Thanks for you respond